# Table extending into margins even with fractional width of textwidth specified

Tags: tables, margins

I am having a weird issue.

I am trying to create a table that requires multiline headers centered both horizontally and vertically. I figured out how to do this using

```
{\centering\arraybackslash}m{<fraction>\textwidth}
```

for each column header and does exactly what I want. However, even when i specify the fractions such that they all add to 0.85ish, the table extends past the main body of text into the margin between the body of text and margin notes. I have attached a bit of sample

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Matthew Mouawad}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

    \begingroup

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption[Brachytherapy studies]{A list of studies reporting cosmetic outcome as well as with a focus on studies from the last 10 years} 
        \label{tab-brachy-review}
        \footnotesize
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.28\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.07\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.15\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.13\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.14\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.085\textwidth}}       %{cccccc}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test & test & test \\
            1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    \\
            1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    \\
            1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \normalsize
    \end{table}
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: Latex table margin issue]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: If you place the instruction `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` immediately after `\begin{table}[ht]`, you could dispense with the `\begingroup` and `\aftergroup` directives. Separately, there's no need for the `\normalsize` directives since the scope of the earlier `\footnotesize` directive ends with `\end{table}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified six *usable* column widths, and those add up to `0.855\textwidth`. However, to obtain the *full* width of a column, one has to add `2\tabcolsep` to the usable width. The default value of the `\tabcolsep` parameter is `6pt` in most document classes I'm familiar with. What you've "discovered", then, is that `0.855\textwidth+12\tabcolsep>\textwidth` -- at least for the current values of `\textwidth` and `\tabcolsep`.

To make the tabular material fit inside the width of the text block, one *could* go about calculating, by hand, what the value of `\tabcolsep` would have to be in order to ensure that `12\tabcolsep=0.145\textwidth`. (Hint: 0.145/12=0.1208333.) However, one could also go about the job much more simply:

- use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment,
- set the desired width of the `tabular*` environment to `\textwidth`,
- set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt`, and
- use the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive inside the second argument of the `tabular*` environment to make LaTeX figure out the permissible amount of intercolumn whitespace.

[image]

Aside: The vertical lines in the preceding screenshot denote the edges of the text block. These lines are inserted because the `geometry` package is being loaded with the option `showframe`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % shouldn't you be using 'utf8'?
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption[Brachytherapy studies]{A list of studies reporting cosmetic 
 outcome as well as with a focus on studies from the last 10 years} 
\label{tab-brachy-review}
\footnotesize
%%%\centering %% not needed
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
      M{0.28}M{0.07}M{0.15}M{0.13}M{0.14}M{0.085}}  %{cccccc}
            \hline
            test & test & test & test & test & test \\
            1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    \\
            1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    \\
            1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    \\ 
            \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have marked as solved as this fixed the problem. I am very new to latex so learning on the fly. I do not understand the last point with the @{\extracolspe{\fill}} - I understand what you said it does but I do not understand the syntax. If possible, do you think you could elaborate a tiny bit? I am not even sure what to search to understand this.

Thanks!

Comment: @thatguy14 - The admittedly somewhat intimidating-looking expression `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` instructs LaTeX to "fill" the five inter-column spaces with enough whitespace so that the overall width of the `tabular*` environment equals `1\textwidth`. (We already know that the usable widths of the six columns sum to `0.855\textwidth`; LaTeX is capable of figuring out how much "fill" to insert so that the whitespace inserted in the five intercolumn spaces comes to `0.145\textwidth`.)

Comment: What does the @ syntax mean? I've seen it used in different contexts but cannot find what exactly it is supposed to represent or do?  Thanks, sorry if these are silly questions.

Comment: @thatguy14 - In a LaTeX document, the `@` ("at") symbol can have various meanings or uses; it very much depends on the context. In `tabular`-like environments, an `@{...}` construct informs LaTeX what to insert (if anything) *between* columns. For instance, `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` means, loosely translated, "insert `\fill` [a TeX parameter] of whitespace in *each* intercolumn space". A separate example: in `tabular`-like environments, one often encounters `@{}` at the start or end of the column spec list; `@{}` means, "don't insert *anything* here".